# How to set Intellij Idea Terminal to git bash on mac os

Tags: git, macos, intellij-idea, terminal

How to set up terminal in idea to git like on windows 
Have tryied /usr/bin/git-shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell path is set under File | Settings | Tools | Terminal in Settings. It could be `/usr/bin/bash` or `/usr/bin/zsh` or whatever you want/have. `git` command is executable, which is usually installed under `/usr/bin/` or `/usr/local/bin/` which makes it available in the shell. In other words if git is properly installed and you don't use some fancy shell it should be available with no additional changes.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you already can use git in the available terminal as it embedded to mac os.